# Are the gods in Indian mythology, who came on earth with some kind of aircraft, aliens?

Tags: india, vimana

I am from India and I have read many books like Bhagavad Gita, Ramayana, Mahabharata etc. in which the characters were using very high technological weapons and aircraft.

Were they aliens because they were using the technology that we don't have today?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in hinduism.se instead of here. It's a question of faith more than a question of mythology.

Comment: @Ajay meena [Lord of Light](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13821.Lord_of_Light)

Answer (score 1):

Basically Gods doesn't live on earth, they live some other place, so may be they are some kind of aliens to earth but they are not like modern aliens.

Since they live in other areas of universe other than earth they need transportation or even humans need transportation to go into the outer space and to meet some gods.Therefore the transportation system is laid in between the terrestrial and extra-terrestrial worlds.

Mostly Gods doesn't need the transportation because they have some special powers as prescribed by Vedas as Astasiddulu(eight godly powers).

references:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimana, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_mythology

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly not provable.  However, various people have speculated that the Hindu Vimana is a flying saucer.

Most famously, this is in the works of [*Erich Von Daniken*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_von_D%C3%A4niken) in the 1960s.

However, a much earlier description was put forward by [Desmond Leslie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desmond_Leslie) in the 1953 book *Flying Saucers Have Landed* (ISBN: 9780854351800).  This presents a more cogent, less sensationalist, argument.

These works have led to a widespread belief that the Vimana is an interplanetary craft, *Indra's Dart* is a thermonuclear weapon and other modern interpretations have been put on the technology described.

But, all this is speculation.  At a fundamental level your question, "are they aliens?" is unanswerable.

Comment: Leslie and Von Daniken have long been discredited as pseudo-scientist quacks.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there an explanation for the flying thingies that doesn't involve ufos/aliens. I feel like your answer would be more relevant if you talked about that.